# How to convert a GMT date from server to a current user's time zone?

Tags: ios, swift, date

I have such a response from server

```
date: "2021-04-24T16:00:34.969"
timezone: "Asia/Saigon"
```

How can I convert this date with specified time zone to a user's time zone?

Comment: That is an unusual way provide dates over the internet. Usually they are either expressed as the number of seconds/milliseconds since the UNIX "epoch date" or in ISO 8601 format (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601. A typical "internet" date string might look like "2021-04-23T12:42:34+00:00" (Where the last "+00:00" bit is the offset from UTC.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a time zone object from the given string and use it when parsing the date

```
let dateString = "2021-04-24T16:00:34.969"
let timezoneString = "Asia/Saigon"

let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: timezoneString)
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS"
let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)
```

Then when you want to display the date to the user you use another DateFormatter instance where the `timezone` property is set to `.current`